# Read text from pdf through OCR in R

Tags: r, regex, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

[image: Data]

I am reading the pdf data in R, through Tesseract and OCR, I have some data in pdf documents like above. I want to read the address, and Gender as Female. How can I read it properly, as not getting any pointers to read check boxes in R through OCR, and when I read I am not able to assign address properly.

Comment: Try `tabulizer::extract_text`. The check boxes may be revealed by special characters or code. Invariably there is a lot of datawrangling required with pdfs.

Comment: The issue is complete document is not in tabular form, Initially some data is in paragraph form, like 1-2 paragraphs, then I have tabular data. Again some data is written in paragraph, and then again tabular from comes.

Comment: @Peter: Can you give a bit idea about the data wrangling that can be done? Using the OCR, I have converted the pdf data into text data. How can I identify the check boxes in R? I don't have to use AbbyyR package..!! Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible answer to the question about how to recognize the check box
Without having a larger pdf sample I cannot be 100% sure this is correct. I've downloaded a copy of your image to do this.

```
library(tabulizer)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)

# path to your pdf

pdf_file <- "wF8L3.pdf"


# manually locate the area of text containing the check box

locate_areas(pdf_file)


# [[1]]
# top     left   bottom    right 
# 11.4404 197.3523  56.6117 316.4253 

#  I just copy and paste this into the extract_text function below


# extract pdf text

txt <- 
  extract_text(pdf_file, area = list(c(11.4404, 197.3523,  56.6117, 316.4253))) %>% 
  read_lines()

# turn into a tibble and wrangle
# this may not be the most efficient way and may need to be adapted for your use case.
# there is no magic. Data wrangling pdfs is a pain in my experience and requires alot of time.
# to determine if a box is ticked or not is done by inspection of the character which is generated by the tick box by the pdf reading process.
# For this to work it will need to be consistent in your document.

tib <- 
  tibble("gen" = txt[1], 
         "mf" = txt[2]) %>%
  separate(col = mf, into = c("m", "f"), sep = "I") %>% 
  mutate(m_tick = case_when(str_detect(m, "o") ~ FALSE,
                           TRUE ~ TRUE),
         f_tick = case_when(str_detect(f, "El") ~ TRUE,
                           TRUE ~ FALSE))
```

Hopefully you can adapt this for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(magick)

################################################
#### Step 1 : We convert the image to a PDF ####
################################################

path_PDF <- "C:\\image_Stackoverflow.pdf"
path_PNG <- "C:\\image_Stackoverflow75.png"
path_Word <- "C:\\image_Stackoverflow.docx"

pdf(path_PDF)
im <- image_read(path_PNG)
plot(im)
dev.off()

###############################################################################
#### Step 2 : We use the OCR of Word to convert the PDF to a word document ####
###############################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF),
                                   ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc$SaveAs2(path_Word)

##############################################################
#### Step 3 : We extract the table from the word document ####
##############################################################

nb_Row <- doc$tables(1)$Rows()$Count()
nb_Col <- doc$tables(1)$Columns()$Count()
mat_Temp <- matrix(NA, nrow = nb_Row, ncol = nb_Col)
  
for(i in 1 : nb_Row)
{
  for(j in 1 : nb_Col)
  {
    mat_Temp[i, j] <- doc$tables(1)$cell(i, j)$range()$text()
  }
}

mat_Temp

[,1]                                                            [,2]                 [,3]          
[1,] "Address\r\t104B \tRoad,\rHoungang Avenue, Singapore\r786234\r\a" "Gendar\rMale D\r\a" "Female Z\r\a"
```

The empty square is the "D" and the square with the check is the "Z"

Comment: You are right! However, you can use regular expressions (i. e. R package stringr) to deal with this variability. I use this kind of approach at my job and it works very well to extraction information from PDF files.

Comment: In the approach that I proposed above, the OCR of the Word software is used if there is an image in the PDF